# i want to print a fixed letter 1080 times in python. I want to print n number of rows without going till the end

Tags: python, printing, word-wrap

Here is my code: `print(('i')*1080, "\n")`. The output is as below. I am not sure how to print a number n number of times without going till the end.

My output:

```
pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
```

output needed:

```
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
```

Comment: What does *"without going till the end."* mean? That is the part I am not clear on.

Comment: It appears that you are wanting to specify when your next break-line will happen and if that is the case it looks like rdas has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A good way to make long strings wrap to newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430200/a-good-way-to-make-long-strings-wrap-to-newline)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/textwrap.html) module

```
import textwrap

print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap("n"*1000, width=100)))
```

Output:

```
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
```

Comment: awesome. text wrap is the one that I am looking for. It worked. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to keep track of current string and then print the combined string ever time the length reaches what you want:

One method is to check if i is divisible evenly by your preferred character length.

```
temp_string = ''
for i in range(1080):
    if i % 52 == 0:
        print(temp_string)
        temp_string = ''
    elif i == 1079:
        print(temp_string)

    temp_string = '{}{}'.format(temp_string, 'P')
```

Another choice is to check if the temp string length is the preferred length.

```
temp_string = ''
for i in range(1080):
    if len(temp_string) == 52:
        print(temp_string)
        temp_string = ''
    elif i == 1079:
        print(temp_string)

    temp_string = '{}{}'.format(temp_string, 'P')
```

There is a library you can use called `textwrap` that will produce the same results:

```
import textwrap


temp_string = ''
for _ in range(1080):
    temp_string = '{}{}'.format(temp_string, 'P')

print(textwrap.fill(temp_string, 52))
```

Or with some list comprehension as a one liner.

```
print(*['P' * 52 for i in range(1080//52)] + [('P' * (1080 % 52))], sep='\n')
```

Or list comprehension with slicing:

```
print(*[("P"*1080)[i:i+52] for i in range(0, 1080, 52)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: I didn't try this but will do. Thanks Mike.