# Python: Writelines - All the way to Margins

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, text-processing

I am working to ingest an online text document, and then reprint it to a text file. The problem is, that there are only about 70 characters printing to a line, which is in accordance with how the document looks online. I would like to change that, so that the lines will wrap all the way around, and will instead go all the way to the margins of the text document, and then come back. Or, I would like to be able to reset the number of characters that print to a line, say 100 or 120. instead of the 70. However, I have not been able to do this.

Please see the following photo:
[image: Paragraph 1 is how I'd like it to come out, paragraph 2 is how they actually come out.]

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/rhetoric.mb.txt")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")

with open("Art_of_Rhetoric.txt", "w") as file_object:
    #soup.text.replace("\r\n","")
    file_object.write(soup.text)
```

I've tried a number of things. Including:

- Putting the text into a list, line by line, and then trying to print out the lines. I only just duplicated the lines I printed.
- As you can see, I tried to search for any line breaks that were within the next and remove them. That also didn't work.
- I even found [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) in some python documentation, but it only seems to allow you to print out up to 70 characters a line anyway.

I'm pretty sure there is a simple solution to this, I just don't know what it is.

I would like the output to my text document to look like it the above in "paragraph 1". Currently, the output comes out in a manner similar to the paragraph labelled "Paragraph 2".

Comment: what you want to do ? separate paragraphs into a lists ?

Comment: So do you see paragraph 1? I'd like the answer to come out like that.

Comment: you want to print it corresponding to it on the site? with same length ?

Comment: No, I want it to print out on the text document longer than the number of characters on the HTML page. So I'd like the line length to be 100 or 120 characters in length, rather than 70.

Comment: If you look at the photo, Paragraph 1 is how I'd like it to look, it currently comes out looking like paragraph 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A good way to make long strings wrap to newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430200/a-good-way-to-make-long-strings-wrap-to-newline)

Comment: No, not quite. I’m not sure what I’m not doing but that is not working

Comment: Is there a way to get it so it will only remove the line if the line break is the ONLY thing on the line, otherwise it will wrap it? I have been able to either (1) Break all the line breaks, but not wrap the text, or (2) wrap all the text, but break all of the line breaks.