# How do I print a string over multiple lines depending on length Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to print a string over multiple lines when ever the length of the string is > 50. I want 50 characters of the string per line but I have no idea how I can do this.

Here is the string:

```
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
```

I have been searching for about 30 minutes trying to find how I can do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried breaking the string into sections less than 50 characters before printing it?

Comment: Well I am receiving the error from tkinter and then putting it into a label. But the window is way to wide when an error occurs and I am trying to make it so the user can read the error message.

Comment: Are you looking for this function? https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap (also `textwrap.fill`)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16430200/14739759

Comment: DIdn't see that one when I was searching for 30 mins...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> s = "configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack"
>>> print("\n".join([s[i:i+50] for i in range(0, len(s), 50)]))
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4
.3.1_8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-
version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cfl
ags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnut
ls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray
--enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-li
bopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --e
nable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesser
act --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enabl
e-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --en
able-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig 
--enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-liba
ss --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore
-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --ena
ble-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbo
x --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libja
ck --disable-indev=jack
```