# Divide string in slices but with entire words

Tags: python

I am trying to divide a text into different parts, but I don't know how to make it divide it into equal parts, that is, each division contains the whole word instead of parts of that word. For example:

```
0 Division: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's sta
1 Division: ndard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a typ
2 Division: e specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
3 Division:  essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
4 Division: passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```

I want that the 0 division contain `"standard"` instead of `"sta"`.

```
def main():
    text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and " \
           "typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's " \
           "standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown " \
           "printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type " \
           "specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also " \
           "the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. " \
           "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets " \
           "containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing " \
           "software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"

    n_divisions = 5
    for i in range(n_divisions):
        print(i, "Division:", text[int((i / n_divisions) * len(text)): int(((i + 1) / n_divisions) * len(text ))])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't want to use `split()`, because I just want the entire string without divide it into words because I want to send the lines of the text to different processes and each process will split the string received

Comment: Unclear: Do you want to split the string into some number of parts of any length such that all parts contain whole words and have the exact same number of characters (if possible at all), or do you just want to "soft-wrap" the text after (or before) X characters without breaking up words?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python—A good way to make long strings wrap to newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16430200/3890632)

Answer (score -1):

tokenize by splitting along whitespace and then use division of tokens (but merge tokens together):

```
...
n_divisions = 5
tokens = text.split()
n_tokens = len(tokens)
for i in range(n_divisions):
    print(i, "Division:", ' '.join(tokens[i*n_tokens//n_divisions : min((i+1)*n_tokens//n_divisions,n_tokens)]))
...
```

output:

```
0 Division: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
1 Division: standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
2 Division: it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
3 Division: into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
4 Division: containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```