# Creating a newline in a string after 20 characters at the end of a word, Python

Tags: python

I've tried multiple things at this point, but can't get my head around my own problem.
At any point before the 20th character in a string (the closer to 20 the better), but it must be after a space, I need my Python code to automatically insert a newline.

For example:

```
string = "A very long string which is definately more than 20 characters long"
```

I would need a "\n" inserted in place of the space after the word string, (the 19th character), and then again after definitely (the 20th character after the previous linebreak)

Essentially, I need a sentence to span across a 20 character screen, and break off at the end of a word if it nears the edge.

A possible concept might involve searching after the 15th character for a space, and breaking off there? I'm not sure how this would be implemented there.

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: How does Your code look at the moment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A good way to make long strings wrap to newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430200/a-good-way-to-make-long-strings-wrap-to-newline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better ways to do this but this seems to work:-

```
s = "A very long string which is definately more than 20 characters long"
offset = 0
try:
    while True:
        p = s.rindex(' ', offset, offset + 20)
        s = s[:p] + '\n' + s[p + 1:]
        offset = p
except ValueError:
    pass

print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code could be improved but you can start with something like this:

```
def until_x(string: str, x : int = 20) -> str:
     """
     params:
     string <str>: a str object that should have line breaks.
     x <int>: the max number of characters in between the line breaks.
     
     return:
     a string which has line breaks at each x characters.
     
     usage:
     >>> str_ = 'A very long string which is definately more than x characters long'
     >>> until_x(str_)  # default value of x is 20
     'A very long string \nwhich is definately \nmore than x \ncharacters long '
     >>>
     >>>until_x(str_, 30)
     'A very long string which is \ndefinately more than x \ncharacters long '
     >>>
     """
     lst = string.split()
     line = ''
     str_final = ''
     for word in lst:
         if len(line + ' ' + word) <= x:
             str_final += word + ' '
             line += word + ' '
         else:
             str_final += '\n' +  word + ' '
             line = word + ' '
     return str_final
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python built-in [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) function:

```
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> string = 'A very long string which is definately more than 20 characters long'
>>> print('\n'.join(wrap(string, 20)))
A very long string
which is definately
more than 20
characters long
```